# Will php sleep/usleep strain the server?

Tags: php, sleep, long-polling, usleep

I am experimenting with long polling. I use jquery ajax to call to a php script on the server.

This is my code:

```
function getlatest($a){

    $stmt = $dbconnect->prepare("SELECT `timestamp` FROM `test`");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($r);
    $timestamp = array();
    while($stmt->fetch())
    {
         array_push($timestamp,$r);
    }

    asort($timestamp);
    $x = end($timestamp);

    if($x > $a){
        //do this
    } else {
        sleep(5);
        getlatest($a);
    }

}
```

I'm trying to make a simple chat system for our office. With just about a hundred connected users running this script at the sametime for a whole day.

Will the sample code above consume a large amount of system resource?

I just can't put this online and test it because I already got a last warning from my hosting.

Comment: the thread will be stalled, so yes. But why are you not using loops ? Your code will fill the method stack after a while until you get stackoverflow exception error. (Best to sleep at client side)

Comment: Well, actually this could work, depends what do you mean by large amount of system resource. I would not use php for endless loop (not even with flush to update the buffer during processing the script), instead take a look at some php socket chat.

Comment: Where did you get `$a` ?

Comment: @CORRUPT sorry forgot. .

Comment: @KarelG client side sleep. I can work with that. Would that be better?

Comment: yes, you can even do that between the response and the new send AJAX call. By this, you have to echo only the output from php without using sleep and loops.

Answer (score 0):

You will make and endless loop with this function, PHP is server side and starts output after it finished running your script. Only then it will be sent to the users browser.  why not use a setInterval in javascript and let the users browser do it?

Comment: im using jquery ajax to call the above script. And the ajax doesn't close until the above returns a value.

Comment: that is because you don't return a value, you keep recalling the same function. remove the call to getlatest within the getlatest function and let jquery handle the interval.

Comment: I know its in a loop. That's why I'm asking 'Will php sleep/usleep strain the server?' because the interval in my sample code is server side not at the users end.

Comment: So, you have your answer, it will make an endless loop, no data will be returned, the function is useless! setInterval in javascript === clientside loop.